# JSON array values are not passing to the HTML form when I use ng-repeat and calling the function in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Desired output I need:

[image]

When I try to get my desired dynamic form output the values are not getting displayed or the data is not passing from the JavaScript file to the html form. Even I tried using the console. It not working, where am I making a mistake? I'm sharing the codepen link and code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVzRmZ

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="inputs">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div id="result" style="width:600px; text-transform: capitalize;" align="right">My_form</div>

<div ng-repeat="component in components">

<span ng-class="mylogic(component)">

</div>



var app = angular.module("inputs",[]);

app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){

$scope.components=[{
  'name':{
    'fname':'{"placeholder":"First Name","description":"Enter First Name of the user","value":"abc","type":"text"}',
    'lname':'{"placeholder":"Second Name","description":"Enter Last Name of the user","value":"ddd","type":"text"}'
  },
  'password':'{"placeholder":"Password","description":"Enter password","value":"","type":"password"}',
  'dim':{
    'dim2':{
      'dim3':'{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"ssds"}'
    }
  },
  'ary':{
    'ar10':{
      'ary2':{
        'ary3':'{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"acb"}'
      }
    },
    'ary11':''
  }
}];

 var result='';  

 $scope.mylogic=function(obj,source){ 

   if(typeof source[obj]=='string'){ 
     var val=[];
      if(source[obj]!=""){
    val =JSON.parse(source[obj]);  
      return  obj +' <input type="'+val.type+'" value="'+val.value+'" placeholder="'+val.placeholder+'" type="text" ><br><code>Notes* '+val.description+'</code> <hr>';
     }else{
      return  obj +' <input placeholder="'+obj+'" type="text" > <hr>';
     }
   }else{  // console.log( components[obj] );
     var subObj=source[obj]; var tempObj=[];
      for(item in subObj ){
       // console.log(item,'--',subObj);
       tempObj.push(obj+' > ' +mylogic(item,subObj)  );
      }
     return tempObj;

     /* console.log(tempObj);*/
   }
}



var res=document.getElementById('result');
res.innerHTML=result;
});
```

Comment: ambiguous question ... pls add more clarity.

Comment: `mylogic` function call has one argument where as function definition has two args

Comment: your `ng-repeat` doesn't print values.

Comment: @tanmay can you just help out with this in the codepen i have shared??

Comment: @Deadpool :- please have a look at my code..its not running ,,i did the same in javascript that time it was running fine ,,,

Comment: <span ng-class="mylogic(component)">  Whats a point of this code???? mylogic function returnsa html string to a class name.Also Span tag is not properly closed.

Comment: @julekgwa : -so what i can do to print values.>.in which way i can print the output?

Comment: @Oyeme : -please help me with the necessary changes i have to do??

Comment: @DeepakVijay removed that `ng-class="mylogic(...)"` and it shows your data. see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmYvGe

Comment: Pls, clearly state what you want to achive in the snippet? or What are you trying to do?? Why write such a complex code and to do what???

Comment: @Deadpool :- can i share a picture of desired output i'm expecting from this code?/

Comment: Also, in your first codepen, `source` is undefined in `mylogic()` because you call it with only 1 parameter, `component`.

Comment: @Deadpool : i added the output i need ...this logic is fine for printing that but lack of my knowledge in angular stopping me

Comment: @flow3r : - so can you comment how to use that??

Comment: @DeepakVijay http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyYMyy

Comment: @julekgwa :- the code pen u shared is not yet saved ..i'm still getting the old pen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I found the answer thanks for everyones help**
"http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVzRmZ"

```
var app = angular.module("inputs", []);
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml;
});
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.components = [{
        'name': {
            'fname': '{"placeholder":"First Name","description":"Enter First Name of the user","value":"abc","type":"text"}',
            'lname': '{"placeholder":"Second Name","description":"Enter Last Name of the user","value":"ddd","type":"text"}',
            'mname': '{"placeholder":"Middele Name","description":"Enter Middele Name of the user","value":"dsdgha","type":"text"}'
        },
        'password': '{"placeholder":"Password","description":"Enter password","value":"","type":"password"}',
        'dim': {
            'dim2': {
                'dim3': '{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"ssds"}'
            }
        },
        'ary': {
            'ar10': {
                'ary2': {
                    'ary3': '{"placeholder":"Sample","description":"Enter sample text","value":"acb"}'
                }
            },
            'ary11': ''
        },

    }];

    var result = '';


    $scope.mylogic = function(obj, source) {
        if (typeof source[obj] == 'string') {
            var val = [];
            if (source[obj] != "") {
                val = JSON.parse(source[obj]);
                var res = obj + ' <input type="' + val.type + '" value="' + val.value + '" placeholder="' + val.placeholder + '" type="text" ><br><code>Notes* ' + val.description + '</code> <hr>';
                return res;
            } else {
                var res = obj + ' <input placeholder="' + obj + '" type="text" > <hr>';
                return res;
            }

        } else {  console.log( $scope.components);
            var subObj = source[obj];
            var res = '';
            for (item in subObj) {
                // console.log(item,'--',subObj);
                res += obj + ' => ' + $scope.mylogic(item, subObj);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
})
```

`<html ng-app="inputs">

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div id="result" style="width:600px; text-transform: capitalize;" align="right">Heloo
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="component in components">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in component" ng-bind-html="mylogic(key,component) | unsafe">


        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>

</html>`

Answer (score 0):

I still dont understand what you exactly want to do, but I think this will help:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<form>
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="data.fname"><br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="data.lname"><br/>
Email: <input type="text" ng-model="data.email"><br/>
Age: <input type="text" ng-model="data.age"><br/>
<button>Submit</button>

</form>

<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

$scope.data = {fname: "Peter", lname:"Jason",  email: "peter@gmail.com", age: 29 };

});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ;i shared my code i dont need the code as simple as this . this can be done by any beginer ..so if you still dont understand check my json and output i printed..

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
        <div ng-repeat="component in components">
            <div >
                <input type="{{ component.name.fname.type }}" placeholder="{{ component.name.fname.placeholder }}" />
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="{{ component.name.lname.type }}" placeholder="{{ component.name.lname.placeholder }}" />
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div >
            <input type="{{ component.password.type }}" placeholder="{{ component.password.placeholder }}" />
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div >
            <input id="name"  placeholder="{{ component.dim.dim2.dim3.placeholder }}" value="{{ component.dim.dim2.dim3.value }}" />
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input  placeholder="{{ component.ary.ar10.ary2.ary3.placeholder }}" value="{{component.ary.ar10.ary2.ary3.value}}"  />
            <hr>
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

[image]

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyYMyy)

Comment: :- just go through the answer down here...http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVzRmZ